# Regex find lines that have a word that starts with "R", ignoring whitespace at beginning

Tags: regex

how do I write a regex for finding lines that have a word that starts with "R", ignoring whitespace at beginning.

Comment: Yeah I tried "^R*", but it doesn't find lines that start with tabs.

Comment: Use `\s` instead of a space to match white space.  `\s` will match spaces and tabs both.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question (probably because of the whitespace you mentioned). You're trying to match a whole line which has a word (could be anywhere on that line) beginning with `R`?

Comment: The question lacks context and precision: what is the input? what is a "line" in the context? what should be matched, what should not? what should the output be in the case of a match?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to find the lines that is having a word which starts with `R`:

```
\b(R[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-capturing group:

#### `^(?:[ \t])R`

1. `^` --> Matches something at the start of line.
2. `(?:[ \t])` --> Matches a  or tab but ignores it.
3. `R` --> Matches `R` literally.

http://regex101.com/r/dO3iT1